# time roundup function in sql same as Mround in Excel

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query for round up a time functionality as same as `MRound`

(Ex: =MRound(2015-1-1 10:10:000,"1:15")) function in Excel.

I would like to roundup the given time to `75 minutes [1 Hr and 15 Min]`.

i am trying to write a query for the same but my excel out put [for given input] is not matching with sql query output.[expecting output same as excel]

Currently i am using below code to roundup but output is not matching with Excel Mround function output.

```
DECLARE @RoundedTime smalldatetime
DECLARE @Multiplier float
DECLARE @Time datetime
DECLARE @RoundTo float

set @Time='1900-1-1 00:00:00'
set @RoundTo=1.25

SET @Multiplier= 24.00/@RoundTo
SET @RoundedTime= ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(varchar,@Time,121) AS datetime) AS float) * @Multiplier,0)/@Multiplier

select @RoundedTime
```

Ex -In Excel if i want to round up `"01-01-1900  12:00:00 AM"` date then it will give `"00-01-1900 23:45"` as output but in sql it will give `"1900-01-01 00:00:00"`

could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: `00-01-1900 23:45` is not a valid datetime value, we dont have a any month or day at `00` , This suggested output can be `31-12-1899 23:45` or `01-01-1900 23:45`

Comment: 1. can you paste the exact formula you use in Excel? as far as I can tell it works on numeric data not dates so I suspect your formula extracts the hours and then works off that - I could be wrong so I want to have a working formula I can plug into excel to play with. 

2.can you put some sample inputs with the expected outputs so that ultimately I can confirm my solution before I post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Time datetime
DECLARE @RoundTo float

set @Time='1900-1-1 00:00:00'
set @RoundTo=1.25


SELECT CAST(@Time AS DATETIME) + 
           CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(MINUTE, 60 * @RoundTo, 0));


RESULT: 1900-01-01 01:15:00.000
```

Comment: Thank s for the reply, but the query output is not matching with Excel MRound function output.